# Disparar exceção de classe AsyncTask

Tags: android, exceção, wcf, restful, asynctask

A classe abaixo é responsável em obter dados de um serviço WCF Rest:

```
public class MyAsyncTaskGeneric<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, T>{

    private final Class<T> typeGeneric;         

    public MyAsyncTaskGeneric(Class<T> typeGeneric) {
        this.typeGeneric = typeGeneric;     
    }

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... params) {      
        T result = null;        
        try {               
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
            result = restTemplate.getForObject(params[0], typeGeneric);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Teste", e.getMessage());         
        } 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Ela é consumida pela classe de negócio:

```
public class CidadeBll {    

    public CidadeBll() {

    }

    public Cidade[] GetCidades(String url) throws Exception {
        Cidade[] result = null;
        try {
            MyAsyncTaskGeneric<Cidade[]> myAsync = new MyAsyncTaskGeneric<Cidade[]>(Cidade[].class);
            result = myAsync.execute(url + "/cidades").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Que por sua vez é consumida por uma Activity:

```
btnGetCidades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                CidadeBll cidadeBll = new CidadeBll();
                Cidade[] cidades = cidadeBll.GetCidades(url2);

                if (cidades.length > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Qtde de Cidades: " + cidades.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Considerando possíveis exceções disparadas pelo WCF Rest, gostaria que a classe AsyncTask pudesse disparar a exceção para a classe de negócio, e a de negócio para a Activity.

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível sim. Mas antes, queria resssaltar que você está cometendo um erro de design: uma `AsyncTask` está intrinsecamente ligada à UI, tanto é que os métodos `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` e `onPostExecute(Result)` têm acesso a UI Thread (veja [The 4 steps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). Assim sendo, você não precisa criar `Toast`s na `Activity`, mas sim na própria `AsyncTask`. Portanto, na `Activity` você instância uma `AsyncTask` e na `AsyncTask` você instância um objeto da classe de negócios para executar o trabalho em background.

Voltando a sua pergunta: você pode adicionar um atributo do tipo `Exception` à sua instância de `AsyncTask` e checar o resultado no método `onPostExecute(Result)`. Eis um código exemplo:

**Activity** com **AsyncTask**:

```
    btnGetCidades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Cidade[]>() {
                
                // atributo que guarda excecao lancada
                private Exception e;
                
                @Override
                protected Cidade[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // em background
                    Cidade[] cidades = null;
                    
                    try {
                        CidadeBll cidadeBll = new CidadeBll();
                        cidades = cidadeBll.GetCidades(params + "/cidades");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        this.e = e;
                        return null;
                    }
                    
                    return cidades;
                }
                
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Cidade[] cidades) {
                    // acesso a UI thread
                    if (cidades == null && e != null) {
                        // erro
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Erro:" + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // ok ..
                        if (cidades.length > 0){
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Qtde de Cidades: " + cidades.length,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.execute(url2);
        }
    });
```

**CidadeBll.java** (classe de negócios):

```
    public class CidadeBll {

        public CidadeBll() {
    
        }

        public Cidade[] GetCidades(String ... params) throws Exception {
            Cidade[] result = null;
    
            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
                result = restTemplate.getForObject(params[0], Cidade[].class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Teste", e.getMessage());
                
                throw e;
            }
            
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Caso o código da **Activity** tenha ficado grande/confuso dá para seperar em outra classe, porém matenha a lógica de modificar UI a partir dos métodos da `AsyncTask` que têm acesso à UI Thread.

Espero ter ajudado e para mais informações sobre como funciona `AsyncTask` veja a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Obrigado Ruben!